# How to set up webpack in AngularJS ASP.NET MVC 5 application?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, webpack, gulp, bower

I have this project currently running on ASP.NET MVC and using AngularJS for the front end.

I am using bower and gulp but want to migrate away to use new tooling, if possible webpack.

I have started the migration process, where all bower packages have been moved to package.json.

I need help figuring out how to set up webpack. And how the changes will affect the .NET Bundle.Config.cs file in App_Start.

**Basic Project structure:**

```
MyApp/
├── App_Start/
│   └── BundleConfig.cs
│   
├── Controllers/
│   └── HomeController.cs
│ 
├── Content/
│   └── node_modules/
│   └── package.json
│ 
├── ng-app/
│   └── app.js
│   └── run.js
│   └── routes.js
│   └── controllers/
│       └── homeCtrl.js
│
├── ng-views/
│   └── home.html
│
└── Views/
    ├── Home/
    │   └── Index.cshtml
    │
    └── Shared/
        └── _Layout.cshtml
```

If anyone has some pointers/ articles/ guides, whatever help is welcomed.

If you need more info on my setup please ask.

Comment: I have worked on an enterprise level Angularjs 1 application. Even I was looking for integrating web pack with angularjs but did not find any stuffs related to that.Reason is AngularJS does not follow styling of import and export ES6 Styling and Component Based Architecture similar to Angular 2 and above.

Comment: @MohammedGadi there isn't much content about it. Since Angular 1.5.x component based architecture is possible.